# How can I plot more than one value in the same date?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot values that occur in different days and times. I am using `DateListPlot`, but it plots all the values for a day in the same day. Is there a way to somehow "expand" the x-axis to show the hours?. Is there anything such as a "TimeListPlot" ?
Example:

```
dateValues={{{2011, 2, 11, 14, 56, 0.}, 107}, {{2011, 2, 11, 14, 57, 0.}, 104}, 
{{2011, 2, 11, 14, 59, 0.}, 97}, {{2011, 2, 11, 17, 5, 0.}, 96}, 
{{2011, 2, 11, 17, 6, 0.}, 94}, {{2011, 3, 11, 9, 34, 0.}, 102}, 
{{2011, 5, 11, 12, 37, 0.}, 100}, {{2011, 5, 11, 12, 38, 0.}, 99}, 
{{2011, 7, 11, 14, 53, 0.}, 121}, {{2011, 7, 11, 14, 55, 0.}, 106}, 
{{2011, 7, 11, 14, 56, 0.}, 106}, {{2011, 7, 11, 14, 57, 0.}, 107}, 
{{2011, 7, 11, 19, 6, 0.}, 111}, {{2011, 8, 11, 18, 58, 0.}, 106}, 
{{2011, 8, 11, 19, 0, 0.}, 102}, {{2011, 8, 11, 19, 1, 0.}, 103}, 
{{2011, 9, 11, 17, 42, 0.}, 95}, {{2011, 9, 11, 17, 46, 0.}, 94}, 
{{2011, 9, 11, 19, 9, 0.}, 102}, {{2011, 10, 11, 19, 5, 0.}, 106}, 
{{2011, 10, 11, 19, 6, 0.}, 107}, {{2011, 10, 11, 19, 8, 0.}, 97}, 
{{2011, 11, 11, 11, 48, 0.}, 107}, {{2011, 11, 11, 11, 49, 0.}, 106}, 
{{2011, 11, 11, 11, 50, 0.}, 106}, {{2011, 11, 11, 11, 51, 0.}, 91}, 
{{2011, 11, 11, 11, 52, 0.}, 92}, {{2011, 11, 11, 11, 53, 0.}, 123}, 
{{2011, 11, 11, 11, 54, 0.}, 120}, {{2011, 11, 11, 11, 55, 0.}, 98}}
```

Then, if you plot it:

```
DateListPlot[dateValues]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You get all the first 5 values in the same column.

Lets try to plot more than one value in the "relaxed" axis that @doctor_image created:

```
dateValues2={{{2011, 2, 11, 14, 56, 0.}, 107, 60, 51}, {{2011, 2, 11, 14, 57, 0.}, 104, 60, 50}, 
{{2011, 2, 11, 14, 59, 0.}, 97, 60, 46}, {{2011, 2, 11, 17, 5, 0.}, 96, 65, 49}, 
{{2011, 2, 11, 17, 6, 0.}, 94, 66, 71}, {{2011, 3, 11, 9, 34, 0.}, 102, 66, 51}, 
{{2011, 5, 11, 12, 37, 0.}, 100, 65, 59}, {{2011, 5, 11, 12, 38, 0.}, 99, 66, 53}, 
{{2011, 7, 11, 14, 53, 0.}, 121, 83, 44}, {{2011, 7, 11, 14, 55, 0.}, 106, 59, 37}, 
{{2011, 7, 11, 14, 56, 0.}, 106, 62, 35}, {{2011, 7, 11, 14, 57, 0.}, 107, 69, 50}, 
{{2011, 7, 11, 19, 6, 0.}, 111, 66, 49}, {{2011, 8, 11, 18, 58, 0.}, 106, 67, 55}, 
{{2011, 8, 11, 19, 0, 0.}, 102, 64, 50}, {{2011, 8, 11, 19, 1, 0.}, 103, 68, 53}, 
{{2011, 9, 11, 17, 42, 0.}, 95, 60, 47}, {{2011, 9, 11, 17, 46, 0.}, 94, 58, 43},    
{{2011, 9, 11, 19, 9, 0.}, 102, 61, 54}, {{2011, 10, 11, 19, 5, 0.}, 106, 69, 49}, 
{{2011, 10, 11, 19, 6, 0.}, 107, 68, 51}, {{2011, 10, 11, 19, 8, 0.}, 97, 60, 47}, 
{{2011, 11, 11, 11, 48, 0.}, 107, 68, 53}, {{2011, 11, 11, 11, 49, 0.}, 106, 66, 47}, 
{{2011, 11, 11, 11, 50, 0.}, 106, 64, 49}, {{2011, 11, 11, 11, 51, 0.}, 91, 71, 77}, 
{{2011, 11, 11, 11, 52, 0.}, 92, 72, 82}, {{2011, 11, 11, 11, 53, 0.}, 123, 85, 57}, 
{{2011, 11, 11, 11, 54, 0.}, 120, 82, 62}, {{2011, 11, 11, 11, 55, 0.}, 98, 81, 77}}
```

I managed to plot them on a regular graphics, but can not use the "relaxed axis":

```
With[{labels = 
Rotate[DateString@#, (3 \[Pi])/2] & /@ dateValues2[[All, 1]]}, 
ListPlot[{dateValues2[[All, 2]], dateValues2[[All, 3]], 
dateValues2[[All, 4]]}, 
Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range@Length@labels, labels}], Automatic}, 
Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, Joined -> {False, False, True}]]
```

[image: Blood pressure and pulse plot]

It is a visual way to plot blood pressure and pulse. Any suggestion on how to use the "relaxed" axis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will plot the date values regularly spaced apart, with the dates as rotated string labels on the x-axis, in a fashion similar to that you describe in Excel.

```
With[{labels = Rotate[DateString@#, (3 \[Pi])/2] & /@ dateValues[[All, 1]]}, 
 ListPlot[dateValues[[All, 2]], 
  Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range@Length@labels, labels}], Automatic},Filling->Axis]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With a little more fiddling, it is possible to get something that tries to reflect the proper flow of the time line. Though it constrains points to have a minimum spacing between them.

```
(* Ease points that are close to one another apart, 
by minimum separation MinSeparation * ( Max-Min ) of data  *)

Options[Relax] = {MinSeparation -> 0.02};
Relax[data_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{sep = OptionValue@MinSeparation (Max@data - Min@data)}, 
  Flatten[{First@data, First@data + Accumulate[If[# < sep, sep, #] & /@ Differences@data]}]]
```

Plot the values with date labels:

```
With[{labels = Rotate[DateString@#, (3 \[Pi])/2] & /@ dateValues[[All, 1]], 
  softCoords = Relax[AbsoluteTime /@ dateValues[[All, 1]]]}, 
 ListPlot[{softCoords, dateValues[[All, 2]]}\[Transpose], 
  Ticks -> {{softCoords, labels}\[Transpose], Automatic}, 
  Filling -> Axis, AxesOrigin -> {First@softCoords - 10^6, 80}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For your revised data here is the Plotting code:

```
With[{labels = 
   Rotate[DateString@#, (3 \[Pi])/2] & /@ dateValues2[[All, 1]], 
  softCoords = Relax[AbsoluteTime /@ dateValues2[[All, 1]]]}, 
 ListPlot[{
 {softCoords, dateValues2[[All, 2]]}\[Transpose], 
 {softCoords, dateValues2[[All, 3]]}\[Transpose], 
 {softCoords, dateValues2[[All, 4]]}\[Transpose]}, 
  Ticks -> {{softCoords, labels}\[Transpose], Automatic}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {First@softCoords - 10^6, 0}, 
  Joined -> {False, False, True}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]]
```

Giving a plot like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Relax` generates a set of new coordinates for the data, which have been eased apart.

These new coordinates then form the basis of the Relaxed plot constructed using `ListPlot`.

Each set of data associated with a date can then be fed into `ListPlot` as a list of {softcoordinate,value } pairs ( i.e. {AbsoluteTime, value } ). This is achieved by the idiom:

`{softCoords, dateValues2[[All, 2]]}\[Transpose]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the very useful "Upload To Se" palette.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad we could help :)

Comment: One last question, imagine you want to plot more than one value in this same graphic. I am plotting blood preassure and pulse, so I joined sytolic and diastolic preassure with a vertical line, and joined the pulse meters. But I can not manage to include it in the "relaxed" axis. Any suggestions?. Thank you @Szabolcs also for your valuable help. Please find the code in the next comment:

Comment: mmmm..., I do not know how to paste the code... I try via a reply, sorry for being so nerd :-(

Comment: By the way, how do you include a graphic in the post?

Comment: @ninescita Here is a link to the tool I used. http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-easily-post-images-to-this-site-directly-from-mathematica-yes

Comment: Thank you @image_doctor. I edited the question and added the graphic I can not "relax". I was having problems with firefox (and Mac OSX), it didn't show the edit toolbar... weird, using Chrome now.

Comment: @ninescita I've added a 'relaxed' version of the plot, with a little more explanation, hope that means you can chill out ;)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! @image_doctor. And now I understand it :). Now that the problem is well described, I have to work to solve it: what you see in the graph is a severe autonomic dysfunction :-(. Thank you again.

Comment: @ninescita I hope you have the best of luck solving that.

Answer (score 6):

`DateListPlot` does handle hours and minutes correctly.  However, your data spans many months (from February to November), so at this scale a difference of a single hour is simply not visible.

Also, I have the impression that in your data the month and day may be exchanged.  You have the 11th of each month.  Note: first value is year, second is month, third is day.

Comment: Thanks, yes the values are exchanged (Spanish date formats...), let me try again.

Comment: Did not work, I exchanged the values, but the data is still "stacked" in the same day.    dateValues2 = dateValues /. {{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_}, 
    g_} -> {{a, c, b, d, e, f}, g}

Comment: As I said, the reason is the scale of the data.  If you look closely, they're not stacked.  But given the tiny differences in times, they appear to be.

Comment: You are right, thank you. And by any chance do you know how to change the scale?. I could ignore the scale if I could plot date and time in the x axis....

Comment: You can use the `PlotRange` option to restrict the plot range.  Of course in this case some of the data points will be off the graph, but the difference between times will be visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What I finally did (in Excel, but I will love to learn to do it in Mathematica), is insert a linear series in the first column (1,2,3...) and use the dates as label strings in the x axis. I guess in Mathematica will be a regular ListPlot, but I do not know how to use the date-time as labels yet. Thank you for your help @Szabolcs